# Parsing modern web pages (javascript/html5/json) using java

Tags: java, jsoup

I used to have a tool that parse yahoo finance webpage, using jsup.

Recently yahoo changed the layout of their pages, and now the page is full of javascript and what looks like json data.

Please see example here: 
http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?ltr=1

Inspecting the page in chrome shows a different view (after javascript had executed and the dom was created) than what the java document looks like in jsup:

```
Document d = Jsoup.connect(link).get();// link same as above
Element body = d.body();
```

returns an Element (body) that contains huge data document that looks like:

```
<div class="footer Py(10px) Ta(c) Bgc(#fff) Py(0) BdT Bdc($lightGray)" data-reactid=".1vh5ojua4n4.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.0.2.1.3.0.$footer">
<div class="Fz(s) Py(20px) " data-reactid=".1vh5ojua4n4.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.0.2.1.3.0.$footer.0">
<div class="Pb(10px) D(b)" data-reactid=".1vh5ojua4n4.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.0.2.1.3.0.$footer.0.0">
<a class="Mend(10px)" href="http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&amp;y=PROD_FIN&amp;locale=en-US&amp;id=SLN2310&amp;pir=Zm7qO7BibUkC.4dK5GxJ95B3DCru2iA5odBNM0pj" data-reactid=".1vh5ojua4n4.1.$0.0.0.3.1.$main-0-Quote-Proxy.$main-0-Quote.0.2.1.3.0.$footer.0.0.0">
```

Any idea how I can parse this type of document in java? I suspect I need to run it in using a java script engine first and then parse the outcome, or maybe there is another way.

Comment: did you try htmlunit ?

Comment: I haven't, I'll try it

Comment: Welcome to the modern web, where what gets sent to the browser is only the beginning.  The static data returned on a GET has little relation to DOM that gets built after the JS and Ajax is done with it.  If you want to parse the final page you have to be ready to behave like a modern browser, build the DOM and execute all the Javascript.

Comment: is htmlunit the easiest way? it's giving me a lot of errors. I'll post a separate question about that.